# what does hasOption do in Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View class?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, blocks, magento-1

There is a method `getJsonConfig()` that relies on a property `hasOptions()`, I don't know when it returns true when it returns false, thank you for your help. (Magento 1.9)

```
public function getJsonConfig()
{
    $config = array();
    if (!$this->hasOptions()) {
        return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($config);
    }
.....
```

Comment: You need to find what `$this` refers to (usually stated at the top of your template file). You are looking for a Block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hasOptions` method from the block calls the `hasOptions` method from the abstract product model:

```
public function hasOptions($product = null)
{
    if ($this->getProduct($product)->getHasOptions()) {
        return true;
    }
    if ($this->getProduct($product)->isRecurring()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you dig the trace, basically `hasOptions` returns yes when:

- product has custom options
- product has saleable configurable attributes options
- product is recurring

Comment: Thanks for explaining I don't know it also checks for the `product is recurring`

Comment: I have echoed the value of hasOption of 2 products : A is configurable product, but custom option field is not set, hasOptions returns True. B is simple product, custom option field is not set, hasOptions returns false. So both have no custom options but one of them returns true. Configurable product is what you call "saleable configurable attributes options" ?

Comment: @YvonHuynh yes because the variations of the product (associated simple products) are handled as an option

Answer (score 1):

The `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::hasOptions()` method checks whether the product has any custom options. The custom options are set in the admin panel on product edit page.

Comment: It will also check for configurable option